# date based redirect in wordpress

Tags: redirect

Is it possible to create redirects for posts which I created last year to a separate subdomain say `old.example.com` and keep creating new posts at `example.com`

like i created a post in 2020 so it redirect on `2020.example.com/post-url-here` and posts for this year continue on `example.com`.
**I have more than 1000 posts.**

Comment: Do the old posts still exists on example.com? Does the example.com url/slug contains the year?

Comment: yes but i don't think you got my question. I basically want to redirect last year posts to that year subdomain